# Is there a way to sort Color elements in a list (c#)?

Tags: c#, list, class, sorting

The idea is that I have a sorting mechanism that sorts according to the red value (later I wanna build on so I can sort by green and blue value too).
I am having trouble implementing this sorting mechanism.

I have a class called `Colorbox` which is basically a `List<Color>` but this way I can put a `List<Color>` in a `List<Colorbox>`.

What my mean goal is that I can order this `Colorbox` according to 1 color (red, blue, green) value. (e.g. so that most left value in the list has least red).

I tried implementing a `toCompare` override (don't know if this works in C# but I know in Java the compare too is called upon when you call `sort()` method).

This gives me a code like following:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj) {
    Color toCompare = (Color) obj;
    if (this.CompareTo(toCompare) == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but I don't see how I can implement my sort by color there or sort in general. Do I have to write an extra `sort()` to override the original.

I don't really have an idea what this sort code should do. Does it order value by value until it can go over the list and nothing is changed? or is this a way too long approach for this idea?

Underneath I give the general code of the class:

```
internal class Colorbox
{
    private List<Color> box = new List<Color>();
    int colorPicker = 0;
    public Colorbox(List<Color> colorList)
    {
        this.box = colorList;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help explain what I should do or in which direction I should look to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot already and ask anything if I haven't been clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want the [`IComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) interface to compare your `Color` types.
Here is a sample using LinqPad.  The `RedColorComparer` implementation will sort your Colors based on how much red they have DESCENDING, which is what it sounds like you want.  Note the use of it with the `Array.Sort` line.

```
void Main()
{
    var colors = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Gray };
    Array.Sort(colors, new RedColorComparer());
    colors.Dump();
}

public class RedColorComparer : IComparer<Color>
{
    public int Compare(Color a, Color b)
    {
        if (a.R < b.R)
            return 1;
        else if (a.R == b.R)
            return 0;
        else 
            return -1;
    }
}
```

And the results are like so:

[image]

Comment: good for teaching, but (b.R - a.R) would do the same, in your Compare method,  since only the sign is evaluated.

Comment: What does colors.Dump(); do exactly ?

Comment: That's a `LinqPad` specific command that gives you the nice looking output in the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can get byte from `Color` Struct. For example,

```
Color slateBlue = Color.FromName("SlateBlue");
byte g = slateBlue.G;
byte b = slateBlue.B;
byte r = slateBlue.R;
byte a = slateBlue.A;
string text = String.Format("Slate Blue has these ARGB values: Alpha:{0}, " +
    "red:{1}, green: {2}, blue {3}", new object[] { a, r, g, b });
```

and then try to order these byte implement ICompare

```
public class SortColorByRed : IComparer<Color>
{
    public int Compare(Color x, Color y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return x.R.CompareTo(y.R);
    }
}
```

and then use it in Sort by passing Comparison

```
var color1 = new Color();
var color2 = new Color();
List<Color> list = new List<Color>(){color1,color2};
SortColorByRed sortByRed = new SortColorByRed(); 
list.Sort(sortByRed);
```

Comment: good, except a color is a struct and cannot become null, the compiler will strike on that.